# bluebird Promisies crud example using nodejs , express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, bluebird

My Fellow Friends, Unfortunately I cant find any examples on how to implement the bluebird promise library in a node js express mongoose app.

My app is setup where the mongoose model, controllers and routes are in diffrent files.

But implementing it with mongoose, i just cant figure it out.

So Please can someone show me how its used. Please see below.

```
//express controller Article.js


var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
errorHandler = require('./errors'),
Article = mongoose.model('Article');

exports.list = function(req, res) {
Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, articles) {
      if (err) {
          return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
          });
      } else {
          res.jsonp(articles);
      }
  });
};
```

//Mongoose Model

```
 /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 /**
 * Article Schema
 */
 var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank'
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

So please if i wanted to use Bluebird promise library, How would i go about changing  export.list

Thanks in advance.

Some Questions,

where do i call promisify on the mongoose model?
e.g `Article = mongoose.model('Article');
like this`Article = Promise.promisifyAll(require('Article'));
or
like this

```
  var Article = mongoose.model('Article');
  Article = Promise.promisifyAll(Article);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok after scouring around the internet for weeks, i was able to find an example [here](https://github.com/jeduan/express4-mongoose-bluebird)
In order to work with mongoose models in your nodejs app,

You need to promisify the Library and the model Instance like so
in your model module, after you have defined your Schema

```
var Article = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
Promise.promisifyAll(Article);
Promise.promisifyAll(Article.prototype);

exports.Article = Article;
//Replace Article with the name of your Model.
```

Now you can use your mongoose model as a promise in your controller like this

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var article = new Article(req.body);
    article.user = req.user;

    article.saveAsync().then(function(){
        res.jsonp(article);
    }).catch(function (e){
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(e)
        });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do an even simpler one-liner at the top of your Model.

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
```

Create your model like normal, and voila. Everything is promisified for you.

Comment: do you know how to do this with es6? 

how would I promisify this `import mongoose from 'mongoose';`

Comment: I believe it would be something like: `import { mongoose } from 'mongoose';
import { bluebird } from 'bluebird';

var mongoose = bluebird.promisifyAll(mongoose);` but I'm not sure. You can intermix commonJS with es6 either way so I wouldn't worry about it @JesusAdolfoRodriguez

Answer (score 1):

Even tough the question is already answered. I think a better way to promisify mongoose is to do the following:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Model);
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Model.prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Query.prototype);
```

This way all modules automatically have the Async functions.

See also: [mongoose-bird](https://github.com/pentateu/mongoose-bird) for a library doing exactly this.